# Angular 2 position of dynamically created components

Tags: css, angular, angular2-components

I´m adding multiple dropdowns via component factory by clicking a button. Every time i add a new dropdown, it appears on top of the previous one, which is a problem, because i need it below. Is there a way to set the position of the new component in relation to other components of the same type?

```
@ViewChild('additionalDropdown', { read: ViewContainerRef })
private additionalDropdown: any;
```

...

```
let componentFactory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(MultiselectComponent);
let componentRef = this.additionalDropdown.createComponent(componentFactory, 0,  this.additionalDropdown.injector)
```

Template:

```
<ng-container #additionalDropdown></ng-container>
```

Comment: Isn't this is more of a `css` question? What have you tried to position them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inserted component's position is the second argument to [createComponent()](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ViewContainerRef-class.html#!#createComponent-anchor).

You're doing `createComponent(componentFactory, 0)` so you're always inserting the component **as the FIRST view** in the container (zero = first position).

If you passed no value for the second argument, the component would be inserted **as the LAST view**, but you can't do that since you want to pass 3 arguments.

You could try to pass `null` as the second argument, but I'm not sure it will work:

```ts
this.additionalDropdown.createComponent(componentFactory, null, this.additionalDropdown.injector);
```

Or you could have a manual counter (this would work for sure):

```ts
const counter = 0;
this.additionalDropdown.createComponent(componentFactory, counter++, this.additionalDropdown.injector);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, `null` didnt work, the counter does!